# Separate even and odd rows into two new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple (sparse) TimeSeries:

```
In[4]: df.head(8)
Out[4]: 
                            type
2016-09-22 04:13:00+00:00      1
2016-09-22 06:13:00+00:00      2
2016-09-22 06:26:00+00:00      1
2016-09-22 06:47:00+00:00      2
2016-09-22 09:16:00+00:00      1
2016-09-22 12:02:00+00:00      2
2016-09-22 16:26:00+00:00      1
2016-09-22 16:58:00+00:00      2
```

The type column is always alternating 1 and 2. It can be assumed that the first type is 1.

I would like to only only consider rows where type is 2. Additionally, I would like to add a new column 'start' that contains the index (timestamp) of the previous row (of type 1):

```
In[4]: df.head(4)
Out[4]: 
                            type                      start
2016-09-22 06:13:00+00:00      2  2016-09-22 04:13:00+00:00
2016-09-22 06:47:00+00:00      2  2016-09-22 06:26:00+00:00
2016-09-22 12:02:00+00:00      2  2016-09-22 09:16:00+00:00
2016-09-22 16:58:00+00:00      2  2016-09-22 16:26:00+00:00
```

Comment: So what have you tried?  The steps you list are well-documented PANDAS techniques.

Comment: @Prune I don't see how this is relevant information in this case. It's a simple question with a simple answer.

Comment: Which means that you should provide your coding attempt, as stated in the posting guidelines.

Comment: @Prune Can you point me to where it says that? I'm not asking for homework assistance. I was not satisfied my solution that involved two filterings and a shifting of the entire series. Isn't SO supposed to be a collection of concise questions and answers? How is my unsuccessful attempt going to help anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know that the values alternate, and since we know that the first value will be `1`, we can use simple slicing here, along with `assign`:

```
df[1::2].assign(start=df[::2].index)
```

```
                     type               start
2016-09-22 06:13:00     2 2016-09-22 04:13:00
2016-09-22 06:47:00     2 2016-09-22 06:26:00
2016-09-22 12:02:00     2 2016-09-22 09:16:00
2016-09-22 16:58:00     2 2016-09-22 16:26:00
```

If this was *not* a guarantee:

```
df.loc[df.type.eq(2)].assign(start=df.loc[df.type.eq(1)].index)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dataframe where type = 2.

```
df1 = df[df.type == 2]
```

Then, add a column with the index of type = 1

```
df1['start'] = df[df.type == 1].index
```